# How can I count how many target words can be made from the alphabet of a given string in Java?

Tags: java, string

There is a string s and an array of names l.

I want to count how many names of the given array with the characters of the string S can be created.

For example)

```
String s = "LILLYBILLYBOO";
String[] l = {"BILL", "MARIA", "LILLY"};
```

Through the alphabet of String s can make BILL twice, MARIA zero, LILLY once.

So the expected return value is {2,0,1}.

Is there any way to solve this problem with StringUtils or other methods other than splitting to all chars?

Comment: Why `BILL` twice?

Comment: String s contains B twice, I twice and L 5 times. So it can make BILL twice.

Comment: There's no built-in for this, you will have to make statistics of letters available and letters needed, and start subtracting the latter from the former. The generic approach would be using "Map<letter,occurrences>", but for Latin alphabet you could just go with an occurrences[] array, indexed by the (ASCII code of) letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasonably simple approach (without doing the coding for you):

- Calculate a `Map<Character, Long>` from your alphabet, in your case:

```json
{
    'L': 5,
    'I': 2,
    'Y': 2,
    'B': 2,
    'O': 2
}
```

- For each word in your array, calculate the *same* type of `Map`.
- Check each keys in each array word's `Map` and track the minimum value.  If any character in the array words isn't in your alphabet's `Map`, then the answer is `0`.  Otherwise it is the minimum value found across all `Character`s.  With some caution taking for dividing by the number in your array words' `Map` (to handle the two `L`'s in `BILL` for example).

Comment: There is no need for converting the word to a `Map`. We can just iterate on the string characters directly and check/update the `Map<Character, Long>`

Comment: You sure could.  Not sure that would make it simpler to understand though (which is mostly what I was going for here - I'm sure there's a world of optimisations you could make).